# Trying to write & append results to file

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, windows

Below the below image of my (fairly) simple app, is the code for it. I need to know how to export comboBox1 (Location), comboBox2 (Medication), textBox1(Quantity), and textBox2 (Date) to either a CSV or an Excel type file, to run reports against. I am two weeks new to C#, and could REALLY use the help, as I have been working on this part, in specific, at work for about a week now!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
       public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
                public Form1()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                }

                private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {

                }

                private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {

                }

                private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    Application.Exit();
                }

                private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    Application.Exit();
                }

                private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                }

                private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                }

                private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                    dateTimePicker1.MinDate = DateTime.Today;
                    dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Today;
                }

                private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                }

                private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    textBox2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                }


        }
}][1]
```

Comment: I apologize, that due to my being a noob on StackOverflow.com, I was not able to post the image of the program. But there are three buttons. After hitting "Button1", I want the selections in the two comboboxes and textboxes to output to a csv file, or something of the like.

Comment: So what have you tried, and what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Have you done any research? This is a fairly simple task.

Comment: I have been watching some videos on YouuTube, and doing some reading on a few forums. The issue is that I am so new to this, but there are so many different opinions on how to do it, so I try using some of the code as a template, but I am not sure whether I am supposed to paste inside or outside of what brackets, and I am still a little confused on "classes". That's the main reason I am asking for the help. I don't want to get so frustrated that I choose a different way of doing it, cause C# seems like a good approach.

Comment: And it's a good learning experience as well! I am good at modifying code, but I'm not good at writing it. Any help is SUPER appreciated!   :-)

Answer (score 0):

- A textbox has a .Text property
- A combobox has a .SelectedItem property

You can write to a text file like this...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx